# Help identifying 8 pin connector vacuum cleaner

Tags: identification, connector, pins

Help identifying 8 pin connector please !
is it cable to motor vacuum cleaner samsung vr7000

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to take measurements and provide dimensions and pin pitch at a minimum. Also consider cropping your images to the relevant portion.

Comment: What's the pin spacing? 2.54 mm? 2 mm? 1.27 mm?

Comment: You can buy the cable on ebay: https://www.ebay.com/itm/153549275651?hash=item23c0400203:g:wrkAAOSwwvtfMagA&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4KoEEBwu7xUrsxeJQagMNrw1cQkkTma%2BaJRqYk3o1K%2FvCle1rGlJar%2FVXCPZTam1CXZ57RZy9GXftxoJDJX3hQT5f61eYE1yICko33Qk1%2FMQW42s22aSx4hnbVBI7984KYps6BGngfEptU5S7saM5FpnM%2BMVhph%2Fn5mVKFymj4lYlPqeh2AP23qu%2BJ1y1mXwSZ%2F8XUsnhE8z2E6at6QCKHLEP0dchRFR%2Fa5ny1p195ukBKKSJGcZkXlKD1uJonMUAYqAAIi4nhfPN3eE6pQAybWqc%2By%2FeO5LBVnvcVSAJsTT%7Ctkp%3ABFBM_LSf1IJh

Comment: Please post also pictures of its mate (the connector that this plug plugs into). For the pitch, measure exactly  the center-to-center distance of the first and last contact, and then divide by 7.

Comment: Having the plug isn't gonna do you any good unless you also have all the crimp terminals that go inside the plug.....  You're best to buy the whole cable as @Rodo linked.